# local fields list not overriding correctly in Django-piston

Tags: django, django-models, django-piston

Has anyone experience issues with this but in Django-piston that doesn't allow you to override fields already set?

https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/issue/192/object-handler-fields-override-local-field

Can anyone help me with a work around? I saw there is an easy patch but I don't want to go in and change the code in piston. Is there a way around it?

Comment: Whats wrong with applying the patch if it works? The only work around require you to limit your handler definitions as Cuong suggested in his answer. Applying the patch seems like a much more desireable approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using django-piston for quite a long time. There are a couple of issues with when you specify `model = Foo.` I simply use it to organize web service's urls, OAuth and Django Authentication. I still dont have any issue with it (yet). If you dont have any special reason to use `model = Foo` and `fields` I think you can call the model within read and create.
Hope it help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to apply the patch yourself, and you dont want to avoid using certain model references on handlers to work around the issue, then maybe just clone the fork of piston that contains the patch being pushed to the main repo:

https://bitbucket.org/rptirrell/django-piston/overview

Its up to date aside from that and its trivial to swap it out to the main repo whenever you want.